# using HTTP post in Java to simulate web browser

Tags: java, php, http

Ok, Here is the simple setup...

> **index.html**

```
<html>   
<p> Login to Blob </p>
<form action='welcome.php' method='post'>
      <div>
      <p> Username: </p>
     <input type='text' name='usernamebox' id='inputtext'/>        
     </div>
     <div>
     <p> Password: </p>
     <input type="text" name="passwordbox" id='inputpass'/>
     </div>
     <div>
     <input type='submit' value='submit' id='button'/>
     </div>         
</form>

</html>
```

---

> **welcome.php**

```
<?php

    if($_POST['usernamebox'] == 'BLOB' && $_POST['passwordbox'] == 'password')
    {
        echo "welcome to BLOB!";
    }

    else
    {
        header ('Location:index.html');
    }

?>
```

The setup (which is in localhost), works fine and I see "welcome to BLOB!" message only when i set the username field as 'BLOB' and password field as 'password'.

---

> **The Problem :**

I need to use java (preferably `HttpURLConnection`) to post the data programmatically and get the response message from the server.. which will just be "wecome to BLOB!"..

I have tried this code but it gives me back the html of `index.html` but not the response from `welcome.php`...

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*; 

public class DateServer
{
    private static final String TARGET_URL = "http://localhost/myfiles/index.html";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String response = readResponse(doHttpPost(TARGET_URL, "usernamebox=BLOB&passwordbox=password"));

        System.out.println("Response : \n" + response);
    }

    public static HttpURLConnection doHttpPost(String targetUrl, String urlEncodedContent)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(targetUrl).openConnection());
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8");

            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

            // throws IOException
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(urlEncodedContent);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();

            return urlConnection;           

        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null; 
    }

    private static String readResponse(HttpURLConnection urlConnection)
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try
        {

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String responeLine;

            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            while ((responeLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                response.append(responeLine);
            }

            return response.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally  // closing stream
        {
            if (bufferedReader != null)
            {   try
                {                   
                    bufferedReader.close();                   
                }
                catch (IOException e)   
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend wireshark to debug this

Comment: But I think the problem is something simple.. something to do with redirects isn't it?

Comment: maybe username and password are passed the wrong way, therefore the phpscript goes into the else-part sending a redirecting header..

Comment: what about `echo $_POST['usernamebox']` and `echo $_POST['passwordbox']`

Comment: just changed the else part to `echo 'login failed'` and saved it and ran  it again.. still getting same index.html

Comment: of course, because your URL is `http://localhost/myfiles/index.html`
not `http://localhost/myfiles/welcome.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are calling the wrong resource!
In java, the request must go to the php script, not the html

change

```
private static final String TARGET_URL = "http://localhost/myfiles/index.html";
```

into

```
private static final String TARGET_URL = "http://localhost/myfiles/welcome.php";
```

because this is what happens in the index.php

the form passes the form-data to the welcome.php

```
<form action='welcome.php' method='post'>
```

Comment: Just changed TARGET_URL to the one u said.. It worked! but it is not exactly simulating the browser is it? How to do it through index.html?

Comment: extra question... What does 
`urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8");` do?

Comment: The browser reads the form-data and generates a new request
he knows the action (welcome.php), the method (post) and the post-parameter (the form-data)

Then he technically does the same thing, but with a lot more code involved;)

Comment: you should consider reading something that gives you a basic understanding of http

Comment: do you know what a HTTP-Header is?

Comment: because `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8");` sets such headers. In this case he simulates  a user-agent

Comment: HTTP Header is the initial data sent through TCP connection before actual data.. It has info on content type, request type (if on client side) and other things.. I want to know what this `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is doing..

Comment: it is a mime-type. it tells the server what content-type the body has

Comment: explains it.. thanx cIph3r

Comment: An *easy* way to know the request made to the server is to open the web page in chrome or Firefox with Firebug, open the developer console pressing F12 and go to the network traffic, clear the results there and submitting the form. This console will show the requests (GET, POST, etc) made to the server, the parameters sended and more related info.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza the problem here is, that he's using java not a browser. Therefore firebug won't help to debug the minimal java-browser

Comment: Using the console OP could understand the URL, the kind of request and the parameters to send from Java side (using Apache HttpClient or another library)